# getIndexRoute after getComponent is all completed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

In my react-router routes, I used plainRoutes like so:

```
getComponent (nextState, cb) {
    require.ensure([], (require) => {
      const CoreLayout  = require('../layouts/CoreLayout/CoreLayout').default
      const userActions = require('../store/user').actions
      store.dispatch(userActions.fetch())
      cb(null, CoreLayout)
    })
},
```

Now I need something in the state, for my `IndexRoute` that can is undefined until the `.fetch` has been completed:

```
indexRoute: Default(store),
```

**Default**

```
import { injectReducer } from '../../store/reducers'

export default (store) => ({
  getComponent (nextState, cb) {
    const state = store.getState();
    require.ensure([], (require) => {
      const actions = require('../modules').actions
      store.dispatch(actions.fetch(state.list.selected))
      // snipped for brevity
      cb(null, Default)
    }, 'default')
  }
})
```

How do I make sure the first asynchronous fetch is done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `then` if your async action return promise. For example:

// actions.js

```
export default function fetch(id) {
   return (dispatch) => 
     fetch('/getSomething?id=' + id)
       .then(response => {
         dispatch({
           type: FETCH
           payload: response
         })
       });
}
```

// Default

```
  ...
  store.dispatch(actions.fetch(state.list.selected))
    .then(response => {
       cb(null, Default)
    });
  ...
```